# Calling a custom made functions from the Hotkey command

Tags: autohotkey

for example i made this custom function , the grid command which has hotkey of  ( ctrl + ' )

```
grid_command:
send {ctrl down}{' down}
send {ctrl up}{' up}
ToolTipFont("s10", "Segoe UI")
ToolTip Toggle Grid
SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, 300
return
```

my usual approach is this

```
!g::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
send {ctrl down}{' down}   ;<== Note : this is from grid command
send {ctrl up}{' up}
else
Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return
```

but i want a cleaner way ( this is my goal ) see below code

```
!g::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
send {grid_command} ; < instead of using {ctrl down}{' down} i use grid_command
else
Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return
```

question 1 :
is it possible to implement this in AHK ? if so how ? the code above is not working unfortunately , im pretty sure send was wrong

question 2 :
can i do also multiple call from function not only one ?

```
ex. 

!g::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
send {grid_command}
sleep 30
send {another_command}
else
Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return
```

thank you for answering

i tried using send and im pretty sure im using the wrong syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

To call a [label](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Labels.htm)ed [subroutine](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Labels.htm#subroutines) from another place in the script, use the [Gosub](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Gosub.htm) command:

```
!g::
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
        Gosub, grid_command
    else
        Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return
```

2. 

If an [If](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/IfExpression.htm)- or Else-statement owns more than one line, those lines must be enclosed in braces (to create a block):

```
!g::
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
    {
        Gosub, grid_command
        sleep 30
        do something else
    }
    else
        Menu, PS_Grouping, Show
return
```